# Tunnel out to internet

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

I'm on a network with no internet access, but I have SSH access to a server that sits on my internal network, and the internet.

I would like certain programs to be able to access the internet, like windows update and my antivirus software etc.

If I install a proxy server on that server I can use the internet from my pc. But I don't want to do that.

Is there a way that I can configure a web browser and perhaps putty to let me "tunnel out?" through the server to the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later versions of OpenSSH can be configured to act as a SOCKS proxy. Run the following command:

```
ssh -Dlocalhost:1080 host -N
```

And then instruct your network applications to use the SOCKS server listening at `localhost:1080`.

Answer (score 3):

in PuTTY, go into the `Tunnels` page in your session settings.  Set up a Dynamic forward (as opposed to Remote or Local).  This is a SOCKS proxy.  Any program that will allow the use of a SOCKS proxy will be able to use it as such.

Comment: I must be missing something here, because this simply does not work for me. What could be stopping it?